# Why is semicolon an invalid character in cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, database, cx-oracle

I'm relatively new to databases, can anyone explain to me why this is the case?

E.g. the following gives an invalid character error:

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)

# cx_Oracle.connect([user, password, dsn, mode, handle, pool, threaded, events, cclass,
#   purity, newpassword, encoding, nencoding, edition, appcontext, tag, matchanytag])
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user = username, password = password, dsn = dsn_tns)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from MYTABLE;")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute()` method takes a single SQL command, and the semicolon is never part of the command. It is used to separate multiple commands executed in sequence.

Comment: Cool, so follow-up question: how can I use executemany to execute this query with the semicolon?  (Not quite sure what the second argument should be.)

For pedagogical purposes of course.

Comment: `executemany()` isn't used for executing multiple statements, it's used for executing a single statement with multiple bindings in order.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now!

Comment: Is it possible to use cx_Oracle to execute multiple commands separated by a semicolon?